# Send a request to a specific function at a URL using jQuery post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

Is there a way to do this:

```
$.post( "functions.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
    .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

But to send your data to a specific function at "functions.php"?

The idea is that functions.php would have a number of functions, but you would want this specific post request to interact with a specific function.

Comment: Hmm, Im not sure what you want is possible. The thing is that you post data to an url lets say www.example/post_same_data 

than you will get that data in a JSON format for example from that URL and use it in functions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to pass a variable as part of your url:

```
$.post( "functions.php?method=myMethod", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
    .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

and then do something to check this, and call whatever method you want in your php file:

```
switch($_GET['method']){
    case: 'myMethod':
        myMethod();
        break;
    case: 'myOtherMethod':
        myOtherMethod();
        break;
    default:
        echo "Unknown method";
        break;
}
```

Alternatively you could include in your POST data:

```
$.post( "functions.php", { method:"myMethod",name: "John", time: "2pm" })
    .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

You would then check `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` in the PHP code above.

Also worth noting from the name of the file it does sound like functions.php just contains shared functions - it would be better to have a dedicated file for handling your requests e.g. `api.php` and then include `functions.php` from that.

## Pre-emptive warning

**Not that you have said you will but be very careful doing anything "clever" that would allow the user to call any function, as this is a really good way to create security issues!**

If you need to call many different functions, then you could consider the use of an RPC client/server like [this](https://github.com/fguillot/JsonRPC) - but this comes with its own risks, so you should do some more research before making this decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a function directly but you can send a request with the data and use $_GET, for example:

```
$.ajax({ url: 'url',
         data: {parameterName: data},
         type: 'POST'
});
```

Inside your PHP script, you should use:

```
if(isset($_GET["parameterName"])({
#do something
}
```